# How to Write Regular Expression for Indian Names

Tags: regex

How to Write Regular Expression for Validating Indian Names ?

Indian Names mostly don't contain Surnames or Last Names of a Person. It Contains only Initial followed by Name or vice versa.

The Name should Contains either Upper and Lower Cases or some times both cases. White-Spaces and Full Stops are also the Part of the Name.

The Person Name should start with upper or lower case alphabet.

I need the Regular Expression to Validate the Names I listed below.

List of Test Case Valid Names:

1. B. Bala Manigandan
2. B.Balamanigandan
3. B. Balamanigandan
4. G.S. Sakthivel
5. G. S. Sakthivel
6. Sakthivel M.G.
7. GS Sakthivel
8. G.S. SAKTHIVEL
9. BALA MANIGANDAN .B
10. Sakthivel .M.G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch all strings containing only upper and lowercase characters, periods and spaces, you can use

```
^[a-zA-Z\. ]+$
```

Here's a breakdown of how the regex works

> **^** matches the beginning of the string
>
> **[a-zA-Z\. ]** matches any character a-z, A-Z, or a period or space
>     **+** makes the above match any string with 1 or more characters
>
> **$** matches the end of the string

You can [test this regex here, at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bC9wU5).

The regex could probably be created better, though, to ensure that the string does not end or start with a period or a space

```
^(?![\. ])[a-zA-Z\. ]+(?<! )$
```

This is essentially the same as the above regex, except it uses negative lookaheads and negative lookbehinds to make sure the string does not start with a period or space or end with a space

> **(** Beginning of the group
>
> **?!** makes the group a `Negative Lookahead`
>
> **[\. ]** Matches either a period or space (in this case, because we are looking a negative lookahead, it will make sure it does *not* match this)
>
> **)** End of the group
>
> **(** Beginning of the second group
>
> **?<!** makes the group a `Negative Lookbehind`
>
> The space matches a literal space (in this case, because we are looking a negative lookbehind, it will make sure it does *not* match this)
>
> **)** End of the second group

You can test this regex [here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sO5oO8)

Comment: The Name Should start with only Upper or Lower Case Alphabets not by periods or white-spaces.

Comment: It does not validate the name .B.Balamanigandan - Kindly check it once.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yB7wW0/1

Comment: It fails for the name Balamanigandan B.   - kindly visit the URL is https://regex101.com/r/yB7wW0/2

Comment: It fails to Validate Sakthivel M.G.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan In that case, if you want to allow for periods at the end of their name, I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution for my requirement.